# Spidermonkey and getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname, spidermonkey

I'd like to have `getElementsByTagName` in a system that supports Spidermonkey. Where could I find source for that function or how can I get that functionality with Spidermonkey?

Comment: A function like that has absolutely nothing to do with the JavaScript runtime. It's a browser feature. You can find it in Firefox. (*edit* I guess it could also be a feature of a DOM emulator.)

Comment: @Pointy I'm not using the engine from a browser -- it's on hardware player of some sorts.

Comment: Oh OK - I think I understand your question now; sorry.  Well the way it's implemented probably depends a lot on the way the DOM itself is implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added something like this:

```
Element.prototype.getElementsByTagName = function(tagName) {
    var elements = [];
    for (var child = this.firstElementChild; child != null; child = child.nextElementSibling) {
        if (child.localName === tagName) {
            elements.push(child);
        }
        elements.pushArray(child.getElementsByTagName(tagName));
    }
    return elements;
}
```